# Trying to Target a button

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

hi I'm trying to target a button to a div using iframe .. I tried so much but no  result...

```
 <html>
 <body>
  <div id="one">
 <button type="submit" onclick="ShowResult()" formtarget="result"> Calculate </button> 
  </div>
  <div id="two">
  <iframe name="result"></iframe>
  </div>
  </body>
```

javascript:

```
  function ShowResult()
  {
    document.write("someword");
   }
```

it seems true but when I click the button it open a blank page showing what in the function.. help ??

Comment: replace formtarget to target.

Comment: doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing alot,

- First do not practice `"onclick()"` anymore.
- Second do not practice `"document.write"` anymore.

I have rewrite your code, enjoy..

**HTML**

```
<div id="one">
    <button type="submit" id="functionThis" formtarget="result"> Calculate </button>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <iframe id="iframe1" name="result"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 document.getElementById("functionThis").addEventListener("click", showResult, false);

 function showResult() {
     var htmlString = "<body>Some Words</body>";
     var myIFrame = document.getElementById('iframe1');
     myIFrame.src = "javascript:'" + htmlString + "'";
 }
```

**Fiddle**

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anplusdre/L8kqt3pt/)

Comment: It's working on fiddle, and i have tried it in my local it worked too. Can you tell me what error you got? cause it is working everywhere